# Send an email via. deferred library in Google App Engine

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deferred

I'm attempting to send mail using the [EmailMessage class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api#sending_mail_with_emailmessage), which, when used normally, as in:

```
message = mail.EmailMessage()

message.sender = ...
message.to = ...
message.subject = ...

message.send()
```

Works just fine; I receive the email as expected.

However, I am trying to add this `email.send()` event to the push queue using the [deferred library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred):

```
def email(): 

    message = mail.EmailMessage()

    message.sender = ...
    message.to = ...
    message.subject = ...

// elsewhere
def send_email(message):

   deferred.defer(message.send, _countdown=10)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/api/email', EmailHandler)
], debug=False)
```

I can see it is successfully added to the push queue on the admin interface, but I never actually receive the email or any kind of failure notification/bounce message.

I've seen the [limitations of the deferred library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred#limitations-of-the-deferred-library) but don't think I'm running into any of those here?

Answer (score 0):

`deferred.defer` takes as arguments a function and arguments to be passed to that function.  When you do this:

```
deferred.defer(message.send, _countdown=10)
```

You pass the function `message.send` but all the data from the `message` object gets lost so you no longer have any data!

Instead move all of the logic into your `send_email` function:

```
def send_email(from, to, subject, body): 

    message = mail.EmailMessage()

    message.sender = ...
    message.to = ...
    message.subject = ...
    message.send()

// elsewhere
deferred.defer(send_email, from, to, subject, body, _countdown=10)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this doesn't change the result for me - the task is added to the push queue but even if I manually execute it, I don't receive an email.

Comment: Emails don't get sent with the dev server so make sure you try in production.  Also check your logs.

Comment: With the dev server you can see some messages in the app logs instead of the actual email being sent.